# Remove escape characters from string using JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I'm trying to use replace function to remove the special characters, but the escape characters are not being removed.

**Input:**

```json
[
  {
    "MiddleName": "Gisela\"mn"
  },
  {
    "MiddleName": "Gisela12---"
  }
]
```

**Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MiddleName": "=replace('(\\-\\s*)|\\s+--',@(1,MiddleName))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**The output I'm getting:**

```json
[
  {
    "MiddleName": "Gisela\"mn"
  },
  {
    "MiddleName": "Gisela12"
  }
]
```

**The output I need:**

```json
[
  {
    "MiddleName": "Giselamn"
  },
  {
    "MiddleName": "Gisela12"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consecutively use **split** and **join** functions such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=split('\"',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=split('-',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simpler way like this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MiddleName_temp1": "=split('\"',@(1,MiddleName))",
        "MiddleName_temp2": "=join('',@(1,MiddleName_temp1))",
        "MiddleName_temp3": "=split('-',@(1,MiddleName_temp2))",
        "MiddleName": "=join('',@(1,MiddleName_temp3))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MiddleName*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes, This problem has the same answer but I just wanted to add this solution for others in the future.